# trying to do a query session for Parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform

using the `gem parse-ruby-client` and im trying to do a query session, here is my code.

im just curious on how to implement most of the https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide. Also i dont know if i created a session to begin with? i think the gem does it automatically? not too sure

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def log_in
    user = Parse::User.authenticate(params[:user][:username], params[:user][:password])
        @username = params[:user][:username]
        rescue Parse::ParseProtocolError
            redirect_to :controller => "login"
end
    def logout
                Parse.client.post("https://api.parse.com/1/logout", {})
                rescue Parse::ParseProtocolError
                redirect_to :controller => "login"
            end
    def query_session
                Parse.client.post("https://api.parse.com/1/users/", {})
    end
end
```

here is log_in.html.erb

```
<h4>You are logged in as:  <u><%= @username %></u></h4>

<%= link_to "logout", :controller => "login", :action => 'logout' %><br>
<%= link_to "test", :controller => "login", :action => 'query_session' %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'login#index'  

  get 'login/log_in' => 'login#log_in'
  post 'login/log_in' => 'login#log_in'


  get 'login/logout' 

  get 'login/query_session' => 'login#query_session'
end
```

this is my parse.rb

```
require 'parse-ruby-client'

Parselogin::Application.configure do 
config.parse = Parse.init :application_id => 'APIKEY',
                         :api_key        => 'APIKEY'
                       end
```

i get back this error when i click on 'test' button from the `log_in.html.erb`

```
201: missing user password
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the initialization of the Parse.client. This is an example from the gem's official documentation.

```
require 'parse-ruby-client'

client = Parse.create :application_id => '<your_app_id>',
                      :api_key        => '<your_api_key>',
                      :quiet          => true | false
```

To use the client later on, do the actions like this.
`client.post("https://api.parse.com/1/logout", {})`, where `client` is the variable from 1st snippet.
In order to respond to the second part of your question, please consider the gem's [documentation](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client#objects).

Comment: In that case, you are misusing it. Use the variable to which you assign the result of Parse.create to later communicate with the parse API.

Comment: also i dont know if you noticed but this is what im using: https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client/tree/v0.3.0#configuration